# Set Workbook Language in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that gets copied to different users with different regional language settings.

The problem I have is, that because of the regional settings, some the macros i build wont work because they refer to translated values.

Examples are Date names and the value for Year.
(Year to Jaar.)

```
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OpenPO").PivotFields("Years").ShowDetail = False
```

This refers to selected data inside a pivot table named Year in the original workbook. however this gets automaticly translated into the language of the user.

To solve this I was hoping I could lock or set this specific workbooks language.

unfortunately it is not an option to,
run the Macro before copy,
Set regional settings for every user,
set Excels regional settings for every user,
rewrite the macro's for every language.

I have been searching for a long time to find a solution but have yet to find an answer. I really hope someone on here can help me.

My most desired solution would be a simple VBA code to set the language of the workbook.

Comment: You can't lock the workbook language. For issues like this with a pivot table, you probably need to adapt your code to just read the captions of the newly created fields (I guess you're grouping dates in a pivot field?).

Comment: Hello Rory, Yes I do. if locking the language aint possible then i am already on the right track. I am currently rewriting my macros to refer to the range instead of the names as far as possible. this has solved half of my problems. just need to find a solution for the months that get translated now.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you are passing "Years" as a String:

```
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OpenPO").PivotFields("Years").ShowDetail = False
```

If a Dutch Excel is expecting `Jaar`, then you need some specific way of telling it. E.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim yearIndependent As String

    Select Case Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
        Case 1043: 'Dutch
            yearIndependent = "Jaar"
        Case 1031: 'German
            yearIndependent = "Jahr"
        Case Else: 'English (default)"
            yearIndependent = "Year"
    End Select    

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OpenPO").PivotFields(yearIndependent).ShowDetail = False

End Sub
```

As you see, you have to rewrite the whole code. The good news is that there are not so many language-dependent words, thus you can use some [MVC architecture](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm), write the words on a sheet and read them from there. And if you export the logic in a function, returning the correct string, it would be quite digestable.

- [Some good reading about it - RonDeBruin.nl](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win012.htm)

Comment: Hello Vityata, thanks for looking into this for me. however that is not the problem. actually LocalFomula. might solve my problem if it would not seem random. what actually happens is that values inside of the excel get translated. specifically Month names and the value for Year.

Comment: Hello vityata, I updated my question to give a better idea of the problem. it has specifically to do with the value that gets translated. the selection for all macro's got to active sheet or named sheet and then select the range if there is any to select.

Comment: @Drac - so if you change it to `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OpenPO").PivotFields("Jahr").ShowDetail = False` it would work?

Comment: Yes. in the case I am working on now it is a dutch machine so the value is Jaar. but yes then it works. problem is this will be used by different users with different regional settings. otherwise i would have just written it for both.

Comment: Thanks for above solution. however, that is exactly what i hope to avoid. My workbook exists out of 8 sheets. per sheet I have standard 6 commands under several macro's. and to update the whole workbook it I have a very complex and long code. furthermore, I can not predict how many languages I will encounter. and I want to avoid as much as possible to deliver something that needs maintenance. that is why i was hoping to make sure that regardless of the regional settings I could lock my workbook language to English. To the best of your knowledge does this solution exist?

Comment: @Drac - If you are looking for an automatic solution, which would automatically go through code and a change hard coded string "Jahr" to "Jaar" or to "Year", I have bad news for you. But, if you do it "a bit manually", with Search and Replace or with a function, which returns the correct value based on `LanguageSettings.LanguageID` it should be ok.